# How can I pause ALL videos (html5) at once?

Tags: jquery, video.js

```
// now pause all active videos
$('.vid').get(0).pause();
$('.vid').get(1).pause();
$('.vid').get(2).pause();
```

That's what I have right now, but it's less than ideal. I'm a bit tired, so I could be missing something obvious, but how can I just tell it do pause all instances of .vid class on the page?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try

```
$('.vid').each(function() {
    $(this).get(0).pause();
});
```

Comment: The middle line can simply be `this.pause();`.

Answer (score 15):

There's no real need for jQuery, the ES6 way (that should work in most modern browsers...)

For all `<video>` tags:

```
document.querySelectorAll('video').forEach(vid => vid.pause());
```

or in your case (looking for the `.vid` class):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.vid').forEach(vid => vid.pause());
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with IE11. Working with FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 6):

```
$("video").each(function() {
    $(this).get(0).pause();
});
```

more general? for all videos!

Answer (score 2):

Video.js stores all the players on the page in an Object in *V*.players so you could do the below.

### Video JS 3.x

**Normal JS**

```
for( player in window._V_.players ) {
    window._V_.players[player].pause();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3n1gm4/SNZAS/

**jQuery**

```
jQuery.each( window._V_.players, function( i, player ) {
    player.pause();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3n1gm4/cJ8jx/

### Video JS 4.x

**Normal JS**

```
for( player in window.vjs.players ) {
    window.vjs.players[player].pause();
}
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery.each( window.vjs.players, function( i, player ) {
    player.pause();
});
```

Comment: It may need the window reference. Added fiddle links above

Answer (score 0):

would

`jQuery.each($('.vid'), pause)`

work?

Answer (score 0):

This option works in all browsers. It is a simple `for` loop to get all the video tags, then pauses each of them.

```
var videoList = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
for (var i = 0; i < videoList.length; i++) {
    videoList[i].pause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hey take a look on working live example here:

```
$('video').each(function() {
    $(this).get(0).pause();
});
```

https://codepen.io/abdulrehman25/pen/xxaXvoV