# Pause HTML Video on exiting a tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a section with tabs. Two tabs have a video.

Only problem is, which I can't figure out, when I click to play video it plays (that is good) but when I go to the next tab the initial video will still be playing - what I want is the video to pause when I exit each tab.

I've tried playing about with functions but just can't get it working.

Thanks!

```js
$('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).data('tab');

    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().children("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
});
```

```css
section {
 background: #fff;
}

ul.tabs {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
  background: #ccc;
}

.tab-link {
 background: none;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 16px;
}

.tabs .tab-link.current {
 background: #ccc;
}

.tab-content {
 display: none;
 background: #ccc;
}

.tab-content.current {
 display: block;
}

video {
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<section>
  <nav>
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="first">
        <a href="#tab-1">One</a>
      </li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="sec">
        <a href="#tab-2">Two</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="first" class="tab-content current">
    <video controls>
      <source type="video/mp4" 
      src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
  <div id="sec" class="tab-content">
    <video controls>
      <source type="video/mp4" 
      src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I think I'd be using the [built-in event](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate) to stop all videos. On a related note, I'm not sure why you're working so hard to toggle those classes. UI tabs already does that for you.

Comment: I never thought about using UI tabs to be honest. An idea for next time then.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I assumed that you were using them based on the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply loop through each video and pause it inside of your function.

Credit: [How can I pause ALL videos (html5) at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485167/how-can-i-pause-all-videos-html5-at-once)

```js
$('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
 $('video').each(function() {
  $(this).get(0).pause();
 });
 var tab = $(this).data('tab');

 $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
 $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

 $(this).addClass('current');
 $(this).parent().parent().parent().children("#"+tab).addClass('current');
});
```

```css
section {
 background: #fff;
}

ul.tabs {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
  background: #ccc;
}

.tab-link {
 background: none;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 16px;
}

.tabs .tab-link.current {
 background: #ccc;
}

.tab-content {
 display: none;
 background: #ccc;
}

.tab-content.current {
 display: block;
}

video {
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<section>

  <nav>
   <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="first">
     <a href="#tab-1">One</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="sec">
     <a href="#tab-2">Two</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </nav>

  <div id="first" class="tab-content current">
   <video controls>
     <source type="video/mp4" 
        src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">
   </video>
  </div>
  <div id="sec" class="tab-content">
   <video controls>
     <source type="video/mp4" 
        src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">
   </video>
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you change tabs, pause and set the video `currentTime` to zero.

```
video.get(0).pause();
video.get(0).currentTime = 0;
```

You don't need to iterate each video, just get the one that has `current` class.

See code below:

```js
$('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
  var tab_id = $(this).data('tab');
  
  resetVideo();
  
  $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
  $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

  $(this).addClass('current');
  $(this).parent().parent().parent().children("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
});

function resetVideo() {
  var $video = $('.tab-content.current video');
  $video.get(0).pause();
  $video.get(0).currentTime = 0;
}
```

```css
section {
  background: #fff;
}

ul.tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: #ccc;
}

.tab-link {
  background: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.tabs .tab-link.current {
  background: #ccc;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
  background: #ccc;
}

.tab-content.current {
  display: block;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <nav>
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="first">
        <a href="#tab-1">One</a>
      </li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="sec">
        <a href="#tab-2">Two</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="first" class="tab-content current">
    <video controls>
      <source type="video/mp4" 
      src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
  <div id="sec" class="tab-content">
    <video controls>
      <source type="video/mp4" 
      src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to stop the video you can use native stop method, and if there are only two videos, you can stop the hidden one like this:

```
$("video").not(":visible").get(0).stop();
```

You can tweak this response if you need multiple videos by using id, detecting the tab you are opening and stopping the video in the other tabs.

EDIT: you also can stop all videos using this code after tab change:

```
$("video").each(function(i,video){video.stop()});
```